# Estou tendo problema com o smtplib

Tags: python, smtp, pycharm

O codigo só funciona quando o assunto e mensagem(corpo) do email são escritos com poucas letras, não faço ideia do que possa ser.

```
import smtplib

import config


def send_email(subject, msg):
    try:
        server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com')
        server.ehlo()
        server.starttls()
        server.login(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.EMAIL_PASS)
        message = 'Subject: {}\n\n{}'.format(subject, msg)
        server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.EMAIL_TEST, message)
        server.quit()
        print("Envio de email foi concluido")
    except:
        print("Falha do envio de email")


subject = "Esse é um email teste, não precisa abrir"
msg = "Esse é um email teste obrigado"


send_email(subject, msg)
```

Esse é o erro que aparece:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Douglas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 21, in <module>
    send_email(subject, msg)
  File "C:/Users/Douglas/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 12, in send_email
    server.sendmail(config.EMAIL_ADDRESS, config.EMAIL_TEST, message)
  File "C:\Users\Douglas\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\smtplib.py", line 859, in sendmail
    msg = _fix_eols(msg).encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 41: ordinal not in range(128)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Se forem muitas letras retorna algum tipo de erro?

Comment: se causar, com o "except:" m branco nunca vai dar pra saber: remova o `try\except` - deixe os erros acotnecerem enquanto voce desenvolve, aí dá pra saber o que está acontecendo e arrumar. Como está, você perde toda a informação.

Comment: Coloquei o erro, deve ser algo referente com assunto e mensagem, mas ainda não achei o que pode ser.

Answer (score 0):

Mandar e-mail pode ser um pouco complicado - com  o método "sendmail" você é responsável por compor 100% do corpo do seu e-mail, incluindo os cabeçalhos corretos  - você está pondo o cabeçalho "subject" - mas um e-mail "bom" também
tem cabeçalhos de horário, content encoding, tem que incluir os destinatários e a origem também (dentro dos cabeçalhos to e-mail, não só no protocolo, por fora deles, como parâmetro pra uma função).

Então, é até legal ter funcionado com um tipo de "hello world" para uma mensagem curta - mas uma mensagem completa de e-mail tem que star formatada de acordo com as especificações da RFC-822 : https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc822  (você vai ver que ela é bem chatinha de ler). Não tem muitos campos obrigatórios de cabeçalho - mas acentos fora fora do lugar, white-pace incorreto, entre outras coisas
podem deixar a mensagem inválida.

Outra coisa, como comentei: não se de ve usar nunca  um `try\except` "em branco" como você fez. Você pritna que acontece um erro, mas perde toda a informação de erro - remova o "tr\except" - faça seu desenvolvimento, e faça testes - quando souber quais são os erros comuns que seu programa saiba lidar (tipo o que acontece quando o destinatário é inválido),  você faz um except específico para aquele erro. Erros desconhecidos devem ser deixados passar até um mecanismo de log que permita que você leia a mensagem completa (no caso de um programa de terminal, o programa para e o erro é impresso no terminal. Se for uma rotina num sistema feito com algum framework web, o framework loga a mensagem de erro e gera uma mensagem de erro HTTP 500, por exemplo)

E por fim, mas não menos importante: usar o SMTP direto para mandar um e-mail é uma coisa de "outra era" da internet - de 30, até 25 anos atrás- email era bem mais simples. Por conta das adaptações que foram sendo feitas nos protocolos e autenticação por conta de segurança e evitar spam e spoofing isso ficou bem complicado - é melhor comprar um pacote de e-mail como serviço de algum provedor como "mailchimp" e usar uma API - aí fica simples de novo. (Alternativamente, seu provedor de hosting de internet pode ter um serviço de envio de e-mails também, com uma API diferente de SMTP).

Comment: Obrigado, comecei a estudar isso para mandar email para os meus alunos, com tudo isso que voce falou vou ter um rumo para me basear, Obrigado.

Comment: Tem uma integração que chama "IFTTT" - "If this than That" - era quase tudo de graça até o ano passado - e ach oque ainda tem um entry-level gratuito  - procure por esse serviço na web que acho que pode atender algo como notificar alunos.